# get an array of radio button values

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button

given an array of radio buttons.  how do I get an array of their values (including nulls)  for example given.

```js
// use jquery to display [Yes, null, null, No]
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
    true     <input type="radio" name="one" value="Yes" checked>
    false    <input type="radio" name="one" value="No">
    </p>
    <p>
    true     <input type="radio" name="two" value="Yes">
    false    <input type="radio" name="two" value="No">
    </p>
    <p>
    true     <input type="radio" name="three" value="Yes" >
    false    <input type="radio" name="three" value="No" >
    </p>
    <p>
    true     <input type="radio" name="four" value="Yes">
    false    <input type="radio" name="four" value="No" checked >
    </p>
```

how would I get [Yes, null, null No]

Comment: could you please include the js code as well, to understand the issue you are facing better, if you don't know where to start [check this](http://api.jquery.com/map/)

Comment: It is not clear what do you want. In which condition you expect null, what does it mean for you if radio button checked or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***1.*** You need to check each `<p>` checked radio box length

***2.*** if length is 0 then push `NULL` to array otherwise push checked radio button value

***Working snippet:-***

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var radio_arr = [];
  $('p').each(function(){
    radio_arr.push($(this).find('input[type=radio]:checked').length ? $(this).find('input[type=radio]:checked').val() : 'NULL');
  });
  console.log(radio_arr);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
    true     <input type="radio" name="one" value="Yes" checked>
    false    <input type="radio" name="one" value="No">
    </p>
    <p>
    true     <input type="radio" name="two" value="Yes">
    false    <input type="radio" name="two" value="No">
    </p>
    <p>
    true     <input type="radio" name="three" value="Yes" >
    false    <input type="radio" name="three" value="No" >
    </p>
    <p>
    true     <input type="radio" name="three" value="Yes">
    false    <input type="radio" name="three" value="No" checked >
    </p>
```

Comment: Yep I really need the nulls.

Comment: @BryanDellinger  glad to help you :):)

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over each individual input grouping and return the value of the one that has the `checked` attribute:

```
var groups = ['one', 'two', 'three','four'];
var result = [];

groups.forEach(function(group,i){
  result[i] = $('input[name='+group+']:checked').attr('value')  
});

console.log(result); // will print ["Yes", undefined, undefined, "No"]
```

[Here's a working example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LmEXxa). Your HTML currently has the third and 4th groups both named "three" so I changed the last one to "four" to better match what you were looking to get as a result.

If you REALLY want null as the response, just add a conditional to return `null` if the value === `undefined`, but seems useless